# Share dependencies from a package flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a flutter library package. 
In this package I used some other dependencies, for example the [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) like this:

```
 dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter
    url_launcher: ^5.5.0
```

When I import my package into the flutter app, I can't reference to `url_launcher` in the code until I add it into app `pubspec.yaml` dependencies 
I wonder is there any way to share the imported dependencies from my library package so that I don't need to import again in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, currently there is no specified way to do this. To give you an example, I would pick this package called [Chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie). What is does is:

> It sits on top of a plugin called [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player), and added some cool controller.

**CATCH:** Since it uses `video_player` extensively to give away the nicer controller, however, **you still need to import the `video_player` in your app**. Otherwise, your app will crash.

**WHAT YOU CAN DO?**

> You can mention in your documentation stating about having that dependency in the project, like the `chewie` plugin does. This will help people know about those things before hand, and I am sure, **if your plugin is great [which is, IT SAVES TIME]**, people won't mind adding just another single line in their `pubspec.yaml` file. Otherwise, they would have done it via `url_launcher` but they can't. Hahaha!

Guess that will give you some clarity.

Also, do give a read on this [Developing Packages](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages)

Comment: Thank you! I just don't want to manage the version of dependencies on both package & the app, but look like there is no way to achieve it like you said.

Comment: Yeah for now @R4j , it is difficult, but I am sure that they would come with some good workaround for this. Thanks you for bringing this up. I have already bookmarked your question, let us wait for it together.